# Adding google map (fragment?) to activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a map fragment to an activity much like the get started guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

My problem is that the app just quits the moment it's run.
So for the relevant parts of the MainActivity.java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Also the (hopefully relevant parts) of activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="252dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rcv"
        tools:context=".MainActivityy" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Apart from this i have also created "google_maps_api.xml" in the values folder (real api redacted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">MYGOOGLEAPI</string>

</resources>
```

I've managed to verify my api working through following the previously linked example to the letter, in my own application it does not work at all however.

I've managed to identify the following error in "logcat":

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
```

Thus to my understanding my problem lies in the activity_main.xml file, what it means or how to solve it puzzles me unfortunatly. Any help is greatly appreciated. Just to clearify, line 78 is hte line of "

Another idea is that i perhaps have to initialise/declare it like a widget?

including full Logcat in case prevously mentioned is nothing critical:

```
2019-10-08 20:45:20.514 7610-7610/? E/e.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2019-10-08 20:45:21.717 7610-7610/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7610
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):22)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):10)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):41)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):61)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):73)
        at hp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17786052@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzc(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzd(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source:21)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1384)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3744)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
2019-10-08 20:45:21.718 7610-7610/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:438)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3324)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add google map api key inside  tag in android manifest file.

```
<application>
    //...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
    //...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your Google Maps API Key to your AndroidManifest.xml as suggested in the stack trace in the following line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Add meta data with your generated API key In your manifest file with the API key you have generated.